# String parameter to a method choice in python function

Tags: python, pandas, function

Is there a way to pass a `string` parameter as a choice of a `method()`. Example below - can it be done in a simpler way instead of repeating the `aggregation` statements?

```
def ts_resample(
    df, aggregation="mean", resampling_freq="60S",
):

    ### RESAMPLE ###

    if aggregation == "mean":
        df_r = df.resample(resampling_freq).mean()
    elif aggregation == "median":
        df_r = df.resample(resampling_freq).median()
    elif aggregation == "std":
        df_r = df.resample(resampling_freq).std()

    ### RETURN ###

    return df_r
```

Comment: `df.resample(resampling_freq).agg(aggregation)` ?

Comment: You could use `getattr(df.resample(resampling_freq)), aggregation)()`.